# How to make rounded corners of JTabbedPane in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I need make a JTabbedPane like this (I made the image in Photoshop):

[image: awe]

But in my look and feel (based on TabbedPaneUI: javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI) looks like this:

[image: awe]

How can I do it?

I’ve tried change LAF properties, but I didn't find a solution. 
If I use setBorder method the swing make this:

```
jtabbedpane1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE, 1, true));
```

[image: awe]

Java changed only the upper left corner as outer border as image above shows.

I need a solution that might use the Paint method on an extended JTabbedPane class, but I really don't know if this is correct or how do this.

Comment: Can you include some minimal example, eg maybe a jframe + jtabbed pane? Also, did you set the rounded corners when you added the border as suggested by the answer?

Comment: Which look and feel are you using?

Comment: I did it based in Metal LAF. I'm developing a feature to change the theme of the application.

Comment: You extend the BasicTabbledPaneUI, I think that a solution is creating a personal border

Comment: How can I do this? I tried override paintComponent and paintBorder of JTabbedPane, but the new border stood over, not overlap

Comment: The border that you "set border" for, doesn't appear to be the border you're trying to change. Overriding the paintComponent method will be tough because you'll also have to manage painting the tabs. Hopefully somebody comes up with a UI example.

Comment: A little more info, [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTabbedPaneUI.java) is where the border gets drawn.

Comment: Thanks @matt. How to override paintContentBorder() method in BasicTabbedPaneUI class? That's exactly I needed

Answer (score 0):

Rounded corners are actually a boolean argument when instantiating a border, as can be seen [here with BorderFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html).

So what we can do is something like this:

```
    pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 2, true));
```

Where "true" refers to rounded corners.

If you are interested in customizing the border further, you will most likely have to paint it yourself, in which case I would look [here](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J4b_CustomGraphics.html) for a further read.

Edit regarding your code:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.drawPolyLine(new int[]{getX(), getX() getX() + 12}, new int[]{getY() + 12, getY(), getY()});
    g.drawPolyLine(.....); // next corner
    g.drawPolyLine(.....); // next corner
}
```

etc. where you repeat for each corner that you want your L shape at.

Comment: Hi omoshiroiii. If i use setBorder it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/5DuPL3L.jpg. I used 1 px on second argument and java changed only the upper left corner as outer border. I need change like this: https://i.imgur.com/AQyuZ7K.jpg

Comment: You will most likely have to 'paint' them in then. The link I provided should help - just paint the border you would like around the component.

Comment: I tried override paintComponent and paintBorder of JTabbedPane, but the new border stood over, not overlap

Comment: Could you provide a picture for reference?

Comment: As to your previous (now deleted) comment, try using g.drawPolyline() for each corner you want it in.

Comment: plase, see next answer with image

Answer (score 0):

I read the tutorial above and tried override paintComponent method in my extended JTabbedPane class, see:

```
public class MyTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane {    

[...]
@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawRoundRect(getX()-12, getY()-11, getWidth()-4, getHeight()-22, 6, 6);
    }
}
```

The result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pRKY.jpg

Comment: See my updated post. You may have to play with the numbers I provided, but it should give you an idea of how to go about it.

Comment: you are drawing a yellow rectangle - Fine! - What is it that you want to do again??

Answer (score 0):

Here is the start of an answer.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.plaf.TabbedPaneUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTabbedPaneUI;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Insets;
public class Bordered{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("border check");
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();

        JPanel one = new JPanel();

        one.add(new JLabel("first tab"));
        one.setOpaque(true);
        one.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JPanel two = new JPanel();
        two.add(new JLabel("second tab"));

        tabs.add("one", one);
        tabs.add("two", two);

        tabs.setUI( new MetalTabbedPaneUI(){

            @Override
            protected void paintContentBorder(Graphics g, int placement, int selectedIndex){
                int width = tabPane.getWidth();
                int height = tabPane.getHeight();
                Insets insets = tabPane.getInsets();
                Insets tabAreaInsets = getTabAreaInsets(placement);
                int x = insets.left;
                int y = insets.top;
                int w = width - insets.right - insets.left;
                int h = height - insets.top - insets.bottom;
                y += calculateTabAreaHeight(placement, runCount, maxTabHeight);

                h -= (y - insets.top);
                //g.fillRoundRect(x, y, w, h, 5, 5);
            }
        });

        tabs.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        content.add(tabs);
        frame.setContentPane(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Somethings to note, The inner panel the ones holding the jlabel have square corners. I've shown this by making `one` white. I've taken some of the boundary code from [BasicTabbedPaneUI](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTabbedPaneUI.java) source code.

They really did not make this easy to manage, but looking at the source for the [MetalTabbedPaneUI](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalTabbedPaneUI.java) you can see they draw each border as a line, and it would need to be modified to draw a curve at the ends.